# Initializing Mongoid without .load()

Tags: ruby, mongodb, heroku, orm, mongoid

I have the following line in my Sinatra app:

`Mongoid.load!('./config/database/mongoid.yml')`

This is nice, but I don't want to keep my connection details in a YAML file, and add it to `.gitignore`. I want to keep them in `ENV`.

I was able to bypass this in the past by adding stuff like `username: <%= ENV['MONGODB_USER'] %>` to the YAML config file, then reading it as ERB, saving it and reading it again with `Mongoid.load!` before Heroku wiped the disk. Needless to say, that's pretty nutty.

All I could find is the definition of `.load!` [over here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/config.rb#L77) and it doesn't look like there's any way around this.

Is there some hidden way to programmatically configure `Mongoid` connections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's all rails does too, it just parses the `database.yml` file in `/config`

Comment: That's nice, but I still would like to ship the app without any database config files and simply use the `ENV`. Mumble mumble 12-factor apps

Answer (score 3):

Building on [mu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31730748/69002):

You can give Mongoid a hash to use for initialization like this:

```
Mongoid.load_configuration(clients: {
  default: {
    database: database,
    hosts: [ host ]
  }
})
```

Note that the hash you pass to `load_configuration` is not expected to start with an environment key like you would normally have in `mongoid.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Mongoid.load!`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/4.0.0-stable/lib/mongoid/config.rb#L82) doesn't do very much:

```
def load!(path, environment = nil)
  settings = Environment.load_yaml(path, environment)
  if settings.present?
    Sessions.disconnect
    Sessions.clear
    load_configuration(settings)
  end
  settings
end
```

All it does is a bit of bookkeeping, loads the YAML, and hands off to `load_configuration` to do the heavy lifting. There's nothing stopping you from building the `settings` Hash by hand and calling `Mongoid.load_configuration` yourself.

Comment: Just to add a little extra clarity to this answer, you'll need something like this `Mongoid.load_configuration(clients: { default: { database: database, hosts: [ host ] } })`. Note that `load_configuration` takes the configuration without the top level environment.

Comment: @MatSchaffer: Do you want to add that as another answer? Seems like a worthwhile addition to me.